# jQuery scroll event is not working IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, compatibility

I have this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scrollMenu = $("#list .side-nav"),
        scrollMenuFixed = false;

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

            if (scrolled > 200 && !scrollMenuFixed) {
                scrollMenu.addClass("fixed");
                scrollMenuFixed = true;
            }
            else if (scrolled <= 200 && scrollMenuFixed) {
                scrollMenu.removeClass("fixed");
                scrollMenuFixed = false;
            }
        });
});
```

Its working great on IE +9 FF and Chrome etc.. But not in IE9 anyone by any chance know the issue?

Note: The events get registered on page load.

Comment: Try using the jQuery `scrollTop()` property, as it should be cross-browser compatible: `var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();`

Answer (score 0):

Changed  `$(window).scroll()` to `$('html,body').scroll()` did the trick and its working now